# Parsing JSON array within array

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code that gets the first 'name' in an array called 'feeds' within my JSON, I would like to now loop through the JSON and get each name. I haven't been able to get that loop to work.

JSON:

```
{
    "title": "Testing",
    "created_at": "2011-10-05T16:23:26.217Z",
    "feeds": [{
        "0": {
            "name": "twitter",
            "key": "person1"
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "twitter",
            "key": "person2"
        },
        "_id": "4e8c847e02edc10035000003"
    }]
}
```

This gets the first title successfully:

```
$.getJSON(getthisshit, function (myJson) {
    var myfeed = myJson.feeds[0][0].name;
    alert(myfeed);
});
```

I tried to loop through doing something like this, but have not been able to get it to work:

```
$.getJSON(getthisshit, function (myJson) {
    $.each(myJson.feeds, function (i, item) {
        alert(item.name);
    });​
});
```

Comment: Please [clean up your JSON](http://jsbeautifier.org/) before posting it - it's a lot easier to read and solve any issues with.

Comment: yeah, good call. lesson learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **for in** construction

```
for (var i in json.feeds[0]) alert(json.feeds[0][i].name);
```

Comment: nice, you should have told me you edited. almost missed that! this works. winner. this json is annoying tho cause it tries to get a value for that weird ID at the end of feeds. in any case, awesome. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is nearly correct, you're just iterating over `feeds` instead of `feeds[0]`:

```
$.getJSON(getthisshit, function (myJson) {
    $.each(myJson.feeds[0], function (i, item) {
        //             ^^^
        alert(item.name);
    });​
});
```

Comment: @hspain Apparently not awesome enough for a ⇭ ;). And by the way, ⇶ ^ ⇚ is a [circonflex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circonflex)↯   :-↺

Comment: i love the arrows too. unfortunately this didn't return anything for me. didn't even get an alert box... hmmm

Comment: @tuddy Note that the accepted solution is identical, but uses the variable name `json` instead of `myJson`.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over all elements, and write to console:

```
$.each(myJson.feeds, function (i, item) {
    $.each(item, function(i, elem){
        console.log('name: ' + elem.name + ', key: ' + elem.key);
    });
});
```

Try it in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CUfnL/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that data is that the `feeds` property is an array, but it's not used as an array, and it contains an object that looks kind of like an array, but isn't.

The properties named `0` and `1` in the object have objects with `name` properties, but the property named `_id` is not an object at all, and thus have no `name` property.

I suggest that you change the data to something like this, where the `feeds` array is used like an array, and where the `_id` property is not inside an object along with other properties that have names that are numbers:

```
{
  "title": "Testing",
  "created_at": "2011-10-05T16:23:26.217Z",
  "feeds": [
    {
      "name": "twitter",
      "key": "person1"
    },
    {
      "name": "twitter",
      "key": "person2"
    }
  ],
  "_id": "4e8c847e02edc10035000003"
}
```

With this data your code will work as it is, and you won't get an `undefined` value when you try to read the `name` property from the `_id` string.

Comment: yes. i totally agree. i want the data to look like this... i'm using mongoose in node.js and can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to just give me this... for now i'm trying to just iterate through. since i can grab the first name i feel like i should be able to get through to all of them...